# Coloring the <div> to cover the entire width of the web page which has floating child's,<div>

Tags: html, css

I have the child  tags of a  tag and made the background-color of the parent  tag to blue. It change the background-color of the block, but I want it color to the entire width of the web page. Even the background-image of such a  tag is not even displayed. Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Login</title>
<style>

    #login
    {
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #registration
    {
        background-color:white;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .logintable
    {

        color:white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

  <div>
    <div id="login">
        <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;float:left">
                <font face="Monotype Corsiva" color="white" size="5">Facebook</font>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;float:right">
        <table class="logintable" align="right">
            <tr>
                <td>email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
                <td>password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pswd" id="pswd"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" onClick="return validate()"></td>
            </tr>     
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="registration" style="background-image:registration.jpg">

        <div id="empty" style="float:left">

            <img src="registration.jpg" height="610">
        </div>
        <div id="registraionform" style="float:right">  
            <table align="right" height="630" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">
                 <tr>
                    <td><B><font size="6">Sign Up</font></B></h1>
                    <br><br><font size="3">Its free and always will be.</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Firstname <input type="text" name="First"></td>
                    <td>Lastname <input type="text"name="Last"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="radio"name="gender">male 
                         <input type="radio"name="gender">female</td>
                </tr>
            <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text"name="phone"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text"name="user"</td></tr>
            <tr><td>password</td><td><input type="text"name="pass"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Re-typepassword</td><td><input type="password"name="rpass"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">I agree to the terms and conditions</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit"value="Sign Up"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even the background-image is not loaded, I have used  tag to display that pic beside sign up.

And this is the pic of the resultant page:

[image: web page]

Comment: You might want to validate that HTML...it's using some deprecated elements.

Comment: I am sorry.
I didn't get it.

Comment: I don't know much about css and validating the properties. :-(
what should I validate?

Comment: For instance `font` is no longer used under HTML5. Also `align` should be avoided in inline styles. Actually, take all the inline styling and put it in a stylesheet where it belongs.

Comment: I didn't know about that font is no longer used in HTML5, which I am using now and about aligns too.
Removed those aligns attributes and <font> tag. But still not able access the entire width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `body {margin: 0;}` in the style section fixes the extra white space around the page.